# If count(data) is below or same as 4, print one or else print two - not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I need some help to think straight here. I have this code to count the correct amount of `forecast_conditions` which is 4; `(count($condition) -1) <= 4 ? ', ' : ', eller '`.

`count($condition)` prints `5` so I must have the minus one there. `$condition` is in an `foreach` so I can loop the content in `forecast_conditions`; `foreach($whome_answer[weather][forecast_conditions] AS $condition) {`.

The code above prints `onsdag, torsdag, fredag, lördag,` which is wrong. Here's is how I want it: `onsdag, torsdag, fredag, eller lördag` but I can't get it right in the code! I have tested all sorts of solutions (== 4, >= 4, != 4, < 4, and so on).

How can I get this to work properly?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here's the loop:

```
foreach($whome_answer[weather][forecast_conditions] AS $condition) {

    # KONTROLL
    if(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'mån') {
        $day = 'måndag';

    # KONTROLL
    } elseif(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'tis') {
        $day = 'tisdag';

    # KONTROLL
    } elseif(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'ons') {
        $day = 'onsdag';

    # KONTROLL
    } elseif(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'tors') {
        $day = 'torsdag';

    # KONTROLL
    } elseif(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'fre') {
        $day = 'fredag';

    # KONTROLL
    } elseif(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'lör') {
        $day = 'lördag';

    # KONTROLL
    } elseif(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'sön') {
        $day = 'söndag';
    }



    echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="forecast-link">';
        echo $day;
    echo '</a>';

    echo (count($condition) -1) <= 4 ? ', ' : ', eller ';

}
```

Here's the link which I fetching the content from: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,59378217,13504219&hl=en

**EDIT (solution but one more problem)**
The code below is the solution but it's printing `onsdag, torsdag, fredag, eller lördag,` now instead of what I was looking for. How can I remove the last comma after "lördag"? Here's how it's looks like if I include `$i` after the "if tag": `onsdag, 2torsdag, 3fredag, eller 4lördag, 5`.

How can I fix this issue?

```
$i = 1;
foreach($whome_answer[weather][forecast_conditions] AS $condition) {
    $i++;

    # KONTROLL
    if(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'mån') {
        $day = 'måndag';

    # KONTROLL
    } elseif(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'tis') {
        $day = 'tisdag';

    # KONTROLL
    } elseif(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'ons') {
        $day = 'onsdag';

    # KONTROLL
    } elseif(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'tors') {
        $day = 'torsdag';

    # KONTROLL
    } elseif(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'fre') {
        $day = 'fredag';

    # KONTROLL
    } elseif(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'lör') {
        $day = 'lördag';

    # KONTROLL
    } elseif(utf8_decode($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) == 'sön') {
        $day = 'söndag';
    }



    echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="forecast-link">';
        echo $day;
    echo '</a>';

    echo $i != 4 ? ', ' : ', eller ';

}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Sounds like a misunderstanding of what count does.  "if count(data) is below or the same as 4" is just count($data) <= 4.  Not sure where the -1 came from.

Comment: Please read the whole question.

Comment: Thanks but it only prints `onsdag, torsdag, fredag, lördag,` with your answer.

Comment: Post your code snippet here properly.

Comment: You have an off-by-one error. You start the count at one, then immediately add one to it once you enter the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiate a variable outside the foreach named $i and set it to 0 and increment it with 1 for each loop and check against that variable instead.

Since it's php I don't think count returns the position of the dom object, it is counting something else, probably how many values you have in $conditions.

Please consider this code, programmer to programmer, much easier to read :)

```
$i = 0;
foreach($whome_answer[weather][forecast_conditions] AS $condition) {
    $i++;
    switch($condition['day_of_week']['@attributes']['data']) {
        case 'mån':
            $day = 'måndag';
        break;
        case 'tis':
            $day = 'tisdag';
        break;
        case 'ons':
            $day = 'onsdag';
        break;
        case 'tors':
            $day = 'torsdag';
        break;
        case 'fre':
            $day = 'fredag';
        break;
        case 'lör':
            $day = 'lördag';
        break;
        case 'sön':
            $day = 'söndag';
        break;
    }

echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="forecast-link">';
    echo $day;
echo '</a>';

if($i == 4)
    echo ', eller';
 else {
        if($i < 4)
        echo ',';
    }

}
```

Regards
Tobias

Comment: As a proof-of-concept he could try echo'ing out count($condition) on every run of the loop. If the counts look wrong, then this is probably the source of the issue(s)

Comment: Thanks! I got it working with your solution but I got an comma (`,`) at the end of the string. Please see my edit for further information.

Comment: I just fixed that error with the last if statement in the end of the code :)

Comment: Many thanks! :D Your answer is the final solution and I shall use it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an echo infront of the count() conditional statement, which would essentially make the whole statement do nothing no matter what the result of the count() is. If this is a copy/paste error, then can you provide more of the source code?

Comment: Of course I have `echo` before my code. It's required! See my edit for the full loop and link to the website I fetching the information from.

Comment: @Erik - Had to be sure :]

Have you tried wrapping the parenthesis around the entire conditional? e.g: `echo ((count($condition) -1) <= 4) ? ', ' : ', eller ';`

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the code...then at your printed example and I noticed...you're printing ','|', eller ' *after* each $condition. This complicates things, as you are printing to screen before the condition you wanted to check is made.

The comma is essential for proper readable syntax, so you keep that regardless.

The 'eller', on the other hand, you can make a check for prior to printing to screen.

So my interpretation of your code would be more like this...

```
$counter = 1;
$amount = count($whome_answer[weather][forecast_conditions]);
foreach($whome_answer[weather][forecast_conditions] AS $condition) {
    if ($counter == 4) echo 'eller ';
    echo $condition['day'];
    if ($counter != $amount) echo ', ';
    $counter++;
}
```

I'm assuming that you can determine the day from the data you already have and made up the key of 'day' for each $condition.

As well, I noticed that your logic, `(count($condition) -1) <= 4 ? ', ' : ', eller '`, if `count($condition)` is equal to five, will always test true and so will only ever return a comma.

EDIT: made changes to respond to new issue.